# return json arrays from symfony controller for many usage on highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts, doctrine

This is my code from my symfony controller:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$queryIndex = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT g.index
                                    FROM MySpaceMyBundle:Graphique g');

$array = array_map('current', $queryIndex);

$response = new Response();
$data = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->setContent($data);

return $response;
```

This php script returns me an array with numeric caracters, so this code returns me the following json response:

```
[1700,1200,1200,1304,1800,2012,2048,1048,3000,5421]
```

But how can I proceed if I have many queries in my controller in order to use them for different things in highchart.js?

That is to say, I want:

> - the **first** response of the first doctrine query in order to have the **series** (column of the graphic)
> - the **second** response of a second doctrine query is made for set datas in **yAxis**
> - the **third** response of a third doctrine query is made for set datas in **xAxis**

So I would like to return many arrays corresponding to many doctrine queries, but in order to use them for set my chart in my view.

Note that the result I would like is not an array of arrays, I would like to return **many** arrays like this and use them in my highchart script:

```
/*the first array of my first query*/
[1700,1200,1200,1304,1800,2012,2048,1048,3000,5421]

/*the second array of my second query*/
[200,558,...........,154]

/*the third array of my third query*/
[another array of numeric values]

...
```

**Not this:**

```
{ "my_first_result": [1700,1200,1200,1304,1800,2012,2048,1048,3000,5421], "my_other_result" : [200,558,...........,154] }

or

[[first array], [second array], ...]
```

This is the script for render a chart in my view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    var url =  "{{ path('myPathToMyPage') }}";
    $.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

So here, the only array I have for now is from my first query, corresponding to numeric value in my database and used here for the serie of highchart graphic (column chart). Now I would like to make two another queries in order to set the yAxis and the xAxis.

Comment: what would be the criteria to get different results ?
Usually you send with your request some parameters that you can use to query the database and get related results.

Comment: Erm... did you mean to ask _"how can I return an array of arrays?"_, because that would be the same as what you have now, but just add `$data` to `$responseArray` like so: `$responseArray[] = $data`, then simply do `$response->setContent(json_encode($responseArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));` to return `[[1, 2, 3], [4,4, 5112, 5454]]` and so on

Comment: @maalls in fact, I would like to use this arrays for some differents things in my javascript code when I reder them in my view. Using a library (highchart.js), I don't want to return array of arrays.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Sorry If I I was confused in my initial post, I tried to better explain what I am searching for. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

encoded json is just plain text, you can do like this for example:

```
$data = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) . "\n" . json_encode($array2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

In this example, json string are delimited by a line break.

Comment: thank you for your answer, is a good one, but see my update in my initial question. Many I was not clear when I asked for some answers. I don't want array of arrays, but many arrays.

Comment: Basically having an array of arrays is how you handle many arrays with json. 
I am not sure to understand what you mean by "many arrays" then.

Comment: see my udpate, maybe I am more precise. Thank you for answer me.

Comment: I see, I changed my answer.

Comment: sorry but by seeing your questions, it seems like you actually want an array of array isn't it ?

Comment: not really, I just want to return many arrays, in order to use them in my javascript code. But as you can see in my questions, I need to recover the array for different things. Maybe I have to encode many variables in separately way. Your answer is what I need but I can't use the arrays separately for yAxis, xAxis ... etc

Comment: Sorry If I I was confused in my initial post, I tried to better explain what I am searching for. Thank you in advance.